# flexnav menu flickering issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the excellent [flexnav](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/) menu by Jason Weaver. The changes I have made to the original code is to make it a sticky menu in my header. The menu is working fine on the tablet and phone devices. Its on the desktop with width above 800px the dropdown menus are flickering and not dropping down from their intended ul or li items. The [prototype](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/menu_proto.html) I first set up is working fine, but this code doesn't have provisions for a fixed menu. The [production](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/Index.html) page has the menu fixed and this is where I have my problems.

Following are diffs between the two pages:

Protoype code:

```
.flexnav {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

Diff for Production code:

```
position: fixed;
```

Prototype code:

```
.flexnav.flexnav-show {
  max-height: 2000px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Diff for Production code:

```
margin-top: 55px;
z-index: 5;
```

Prototype code:

```
.menu-button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ff8400;
  color: #222222;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Diff for Production code:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
```

Added media query for Production code only:

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 481px) {

  .flexnav-show {
    margin-top: 0px !important; } }
```

Thanks
-Sohail

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://github.com/indyplanets/flexnav/issues/76) :

Use the flexnav plugin along with the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin in the following way :

```
$(".flexnav").flexNav({

         'animationSpeed' : 'fast',
         'calcItemWidths': true , // dynamically calcs top level nav item widths
         'hoverIntent': true, // true for use with hoverIntent plugin
         'hoverIntentTimeout': 150 // hoverIntent default timeout     

    });
```

And you have to download the hoverIntent plugin to use it as it is not included with the flexnav plugin.